# How can I debug the content of the response of WebClient in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following method:

```
public Mono<Response> sendFile(final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    Mono<Response> response = webClient.post()
                .uri(new URI("someurl"))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiValueMap))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
    return response;
}
```

and I want to put a break point and debug the response that comes back before webClient converts the response into a Mono. I am using IntelliJ but not sure how to see the response that comes back before it tries to convert into the `Response.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to debug the response that comes back before it is converted into Response.class, you can add a .log() operator to your reactive stream. This will log the events (such as requests, responses, etc.) that occur during the stream's execution. You can then set a breakpoint after the .log() operator and inspect the contents of the response.

Here's an updated version of your method with the .log() operator added:

```
public Mono<Response> sendFile(final MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    multiValueMap.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(multipartFile.getBytes()));
return webClient.post()
        .uri(new URI("someurl"))
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multiValueMap))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Response.class)
        .log(); // Add the log() operator here
```

}

After running this code in debug mode and hitting the breakpoint, you can inspect the contents of the response by hovering over the response variable or expanding it in the variables tab of the debugger. You can also use the Evaluate Expression feature in IntelliJ to print out the contents of the response using something like response.block().